# How to use @media screen and @-moz-document at the same time?

Tags: css

How would I use `@media screen` and `@-moz-document` rules together. Trying to set a rule for only viewing in firefox at a certain width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
@media screen and (min-width : 500px){

    div { color: green; } // div color green default

    @-moz-document regexp('http:.*'){
        div { color:red; } // red in FF/Gecko
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KRvqd/4/) and [**More Here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@-moz-document).

Comment: This didn't work for me (the FF-specific block was there, but it wasn't inside the media query). You should do it the other way around: put @media inside of @-moz-document.